# Microsoft Onenote iPhone app is not syncing

Tags: ios, onenote

Any tip for troubleshooting? I've already tried closing and reopening my notebook.

Comment: did you try removing and adding the onedrive account back?

Comment: Yes i did. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into occasional sync issues and the two things that have worked for me is either changing the password on the live.com account via the web interface or removing OneNote from the IOS device and reinstalling it.

Comment: I tried removing from my device and reinstalling it. Didn't work.